# Applying a function to a dask dataframe results in a TypeError deriving from the args

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, dask

I have a piece of code involving a function and a **dask dataframe** (`df1`). The dataframe already exists before the function so when I do `meta=df1.dtypes` I am calling existing types. This is the code:

```
def my_function(group, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    # some operations

df1 = df1.groupby("Sequence").apply(my_function, args=[arg1, arg2, arg3], meta=df1.dtypes)
```

It returns the following error:

```
TypeError: my_function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'
```

Anyone has any idea of why? I cannot find a solution online and I am following the guidelines in the DASK API so I don't get why I get an error. The `args=...` should be parsed properly, and they represent the *additional* arguments for the function (the first one being the result of `groupby()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in pandas, you provide additional arguments in `*args`, not an argument named `args`.

```
In [14]: df = dask.datasets.timeseries()

In [15]: def myfunc(x, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    ...:     return x.mean()
    ...:

In [16]: df.groupby("id")[['x', 'y']].apply(myfunc, meta={'x': 'f8', 'y': 'f8'}, arg1=1, arg2=2, arg3=3)
Out[16]:
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                      x        y
npartitions=30
                float64  float64
                    ...      ...
...                 ...      ...
                    ...      ...
                    ...      ...
Dask Name: myfunc, 303 tasks
```

Comment: This explains why with one argument it works, and with two it didn't. Thank you, I got it all wrong!